# python: detecting conneciton lost on ftplib retrlines

Tags: python, exception, ftp, connection, ftplib

Downloading lots of files via ftplib from different directories.  Using retrlines to download.   The following snippet is called for 100's of files within a loop.   The fn refers to the remote filename.

I am trying to find clean way to get the errno so I can recover connection if errno>400. I thought I would parse str(e) from ftplib.all_errors but the errno is inconsistent ... so put hack to parse message.

I am now confused as to the form of the exceptions... e is supposed to be tuple... but discovered I can reference e.errno/e.strerror.   Since FTP RETR error(line>8192) is intermittent... not sure which is best approach so I decided to post this question.  Any tips would be helpful.

```
   try:
        results = ftpID.retrlines("RETR " + fn, handler)
        return True
   except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        logging(str(cmd) + " (gettxt.ftp)"
                     +"FTP ERROR({0}): {1} on {2]".format(e.errno, e.strerror, fn))
        # Check for connection lost, line > 8192  -- connection is lost
        # Doc on ftp exception ftplib.all_errors is unclear about errno. messy
        # some str(e) does not give errno but others do?
        # OLD WAY: if str(e).find('8192') != -1 :
        if e.strerror.find('8192') != -1 :
            logging(" : Fatal FTP ERROR - connection lost")
            close()
            ftpID = None
        # try: self.ftpID.voidcmd("NOOP") ; exception: self.ftpID = None; return None
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        logging(str(cmd) + " (gettxt) " + str(e))
        return False
```

PS. I am aware of documentation: 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.error_reply
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.all_errors
And looked at ten's of exception posts... still unclear for advanced handling of exceptions.